# HTTP Status 404 - Using Spring+Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, programmatic-config

I am beginner to Spring and I am working on my learning project. With below code, I can view the index.jsp but not test.jsp. I use Spring 4.0.1+ Tomcat 7.0.52 + STS 3.4.0.

Webapp.java

```
package springweb;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class Webapp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{ "/" };
    }
}
```

IndexController.java

```
package springweb.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String index() {
        logger.info("Welcome Index!");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
package springweb.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);
    @RequestMapping(value="/test/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        logger.info("Welcome test!");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
package springweb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"springweb.controller"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the last / in /test/ is incorrect

Comment: I changed it /test and browse http://localhost:8080/mte/test, still the same result - HTTP Status 404

Comment: Do you get "Welcome Index!" on your log when you go to index?

Comment: No, there is no "Welcome Index!" on log

Comment: It should be localhost:8080/mte/test/ and the reason I failed is because I did not include jstl as dependency. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for 100% free xml:

1. Set property for the DispatcherServlet

   ```
   public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
           return new Class[] { RootConfig.class  };
       }

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
           return new Class[] {AppConfig.class  };
       }

       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
           return new String[] { "/" };
       }

       //that's important!!
       @Override
       protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
           boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
           if(!done) throw new RuntimeException();
       }

   }
   ```
2. Create @ControllerAdvice:

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class AdviceController {

       @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
       public String handle(Exception ex) {
           return "redirect:/404";
       }

       @RequestMapping(value = {"/404"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String NotFoudPage() {
           return "404";

       }

   }
   ```

that's all